# php, phpmyadmin. Проблема с базой данных

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, mysqli, phpmyadmin

У меня есть `index.php`, `db.php` и база данных. Проблема вот такая: при выводе статей из базы данных, на сайт из базы выводится только последнее имя для всех имен в выборке. То есть, у меня есть четыре имени Иван, Петр, Николай, Владимир. Выводит информацию о Владимире для всех статей.

Вот мой код:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>

<?php require "db.php" ?> 
<?php
      $singles = get_singles_all();
      foreach ($singles as $single):

    // $author = get_author_by_id();
    // foreach ($author as $authors):


       ?>


      <?php //$author_name = get_author_by_id($single["author_id"]); ?>

        <div id="wrapper">
          <div class="headline-block">
            <img src="img/test.jpg" alt="">
            <p class="category"><?php echo $authors["author_name"]; ?></p>
            <h3><?php echo $single["title"]; ?></h3>
            <p><?php echo $single["text"]; ?></p>
            <i class="fas fa-user"></i><a class="author" href="#"><?php echo $single["author_id"]; ?></a>
            <i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i><a class="date" href="#">12.12.2019</a>
            <i class="far fa-eye"></i><a class="views" href="#"><?php echo $single["views"]; ?></a>
            <i class="fas fa-comment"></i><a class="comments" href="#"><?php echo $single["comments"]; ?></a>
       </div>
```

```php
<?php
    $dbhost = "localhost";
    $dbname = "test_saneto";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "alex123crime";

    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost; dbname=$dbname", $username, $password); // Подключение к БД

    // Получение всех статей
    function get_singles_all() {
        global $db;
        $singles = $db -> query("SELECT * FROM single");
        return $singles;
    }

  // Получение названия категории по ее id
    function get_author_by_id() {
        global $db;
        $author = $db->query("SELECT * FROM authors");
        return $author;
    }

    $author = get_author_by_id();
    foreach ($author as $authors):

    // for($i = 0; $i <= count($authors); $i++) {
    //  echo $authors[$i];
    // }

?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Сделайте `var_dump` выборки из бд и приложите к вопросу.

Comment: У вас как минимум не хватает условия WHERE в этом запросе: SELECT * FROM authors; и  фунция get_author_by_id не принимает никаких параметров, а вызываете её с параметром.

Answer (score 1):

Кратко пересказываю букварь по базам данных и работе с ними из пхп.

- База данных - это не набор счетных палочек. Кроме запросов `SELECT * FROM table` бывают еще и другие. Например, с условием WHERE. Которые позволяют выбрать нужную запись сразу, не перебирая все палочки по одной. Это особенно бывает полезно, когда количество палочек перваливает за сотни тысяч.
- Для запросов, в которых используются переменные, необходимо исользовать prepare/execute в PDO

Поэтому если переписывать get_author_by_id буквально, то это должно быть так

```
function get_author_by_id($id) {
    global $db;
    $stmt = $db->query("SELECT * FROM authors WHERE id=?");
    $stmt->execute([$id]);
    return $stmt->fetch();
}
```

Но на самом деле здесь нужен только один запрос, который использует JOIN

Answer (score -2):

У вас endforeach в db.php и по коду он раньше foreach:

Comment: скорее всего он находится ниже показанного нам кода